# Installing requirements with pip in an environment terminates (2.7)

Tags: python-2.7, virtualenv

I'm trying to setup my work environment on my new MBP M1. The executable is python2.7, so I've been trying to create a virtualenv and install the requirements.

Alas, I can not.

I create an environment, and get the output:

```sh
virtualenv env
created virtual environment CPython2.7.16.final.0-64 in 183ms
  creator CPython2macOsFramework(dest=/Users/v/dev/skolplattformen/env, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, wheel=bundle, setuptools=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/Users/v/Library/Application Support/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==20.3.3, setuptools==44.1.1, wheel==0.36.2
  activators PythonActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,BashActivator
```

Then I activate that environment, and try to pip install the requirements.

Although, I get this

```sh
1716 killed     pip2.7 install -r requirements.txt
```

I can't find anything in `system.log`, I can't find what process 1716 is...

`which pip2.7` points to the right place, although `which pip`, in the environment, says `pip: aliased to noglob pip`.

I can't execute a python script either in the environment, or open a repl, it gives the same kill message.

Comment: It is possible to do a pip2.7 install outside of the environment... I really need to work, how bad would it be to keep doing this...? It hurts thinking about it

Comment: Most probably not enough memory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by downloading Python 2.7 from https://www.python.org/ to replace the system's default.